# Creating and pushing elements in an new array depends on conditions

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript, for-loop, multidimensional-array

My Data Array

```
data:[
0:{ 
   id:1 ,.....
   competetion:[ 
          0:{
              id: 1....,
              match:[ 
                      0:{id: 1 ......}, 
                      1:{same}
                      .
                      .
                    ]
          1:{same}]},
          2:{same}
          .
          .
        ]
  },
1:{same},
2:{same}
.
.
.
]
```

For `data[]` i able to create a new array(`sportarr[]`) with pushing elements but i want to create for the same as `competetion[]` and `match[]` in the same array `sportarr[]` 
If there any other way to do it please Help me...

My Code: Here i am looping it:

```
this.sportsSidebar = response.data;   // My data Array (this.sportsSidebar)
const arrlength = response.data.length; 
for (let i = 0; i < arrlength; i++) {
    this.sportarr.push({       // I declared a new array where i want to push the element
      id: i,
      value: false
    });
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you want your own content based on the mapping what I will suggest is that first iterate through the array then map each match and competetion and write your own logic inside the map

```
 const arrlength = data.length;
      for (let i = 0; i < arrlength; i++) {
        let competition = [];
        competition = data[i].competetion.map( (val, index) => {
          #write your own logic to produce the required outcome
          return {
              id: index,
              value: false
          };
        });
        this.sportarr.push({
          id: i,
          value: false,
          competetion: competition
        });
        console.log('myarrr...', this.sportarr);
```

Answer (score 2):

i Appriciate Pathikrit Sanyal and Fahd Lihidheb For the ansers 
Here Is my Change according to Pathikrit Sanyal

```
  for (let i = 0; i < arrlength; i++) {
        let competition = [];
        competition = response.data[i].competetion.map((val, index) => {
          let match = [];
          match = val.match.map((value, indx) => {
            return {
              id: indx,
              value: false
            };
          });
          return {
            id: index,
            value: false,
            match
          };
        });
        this.sportarr.push({
          id: i,
          value: false,
          competetion: competition
        });
        console.log('myarrr...', this.sportarr);
      }
```

Now i am getting what i wanted

Answer (score 1):

i am not sure if you are trying to create an array for each nasted array (competetion and match) or not, but here you go

```
this.sportsSidebar = response.data;   // My data Array (this.sportsSidebar)


const competetionList = // Array of competetions
    [].concat.apply([], this.sportsSidebar.map(item => item.competetion));

const matchList = // Array of matchs
    [].concat.apply([], competetionList .map(item => item.match));
}
```